# Use rand() to generate numbers in division table

Tags: c++

This is the output I'm trying to achieve:

> (randomized var1)/(randomized var2)=
>   Ans:(var ans)

I've already done addition, subtraction and multiplication but I encountered difficulty with division because I need the exact dividend and divisor to divide so that it would not be difficult to answer.

Example:

> 40/5=
>   Ans: 8

not this one:

> 7/5=
>   ans: float value

Here is my code:

```
int x,num,num2,ans,quo,score=0;
time_t t;

clrscr();

for(x=0;x<5;x++)
{
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    num2=rand()%10;
    quo=num/num2;

    if(num2==1)
    {
        num=rand()%9;
    }
    else if(num2==2)
    {
        num=2 + (2 * rand ()) %18; //this should return a value divisible by 2(ranges 0-18)
    }
    else if(num2==3)
    {
        num=rand()% //this should return a value divisible by 3 only (ranges 0-27)
    }
    else if(num2==4)
    {
        num=rand()% //this should return a value divisible by 4 only (ranges 0-36)
    }
    else if(num2==5)
    {
        num=rand()% //this should return a value divisible by 5 only (ranges 0-45)
    }
    else if(num2==6)
    {
        num=rand()% //this should return a value divisible by 6 only (ranges 0-54)
    }
    else if(num2==7)
    {
        num=rand()% //this should return a value divisible by 7 only (ranges 0-63)
    }
    else if(num2==8)
    {
        num=rand()% //this should return a value divisible by 8 only (ranges 0-72)
    }
    else if(num2==9)
    {
        num=rand()% //this should return a value divisible by 9 only (ranges 0-81)
    }
    else if(num2==10)
    {
        num=rand()% //this should return a value divisible by 10 only (ranges 0-90)
    }
    else
    {
    }

    gotoxy(30,14);
    printf("\n%d / %d = ",num,num2);
    printf("\nAns: ");
    scanf("%d",&ans);
}
```

Comment: Run it backwards? Given x / y = z, generate y and z, then solve for x.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes a little common sense can go a long way.

Answer (score 3):

You can just pick a random result and create the question

```
denominator = 14 (randomly chosen)
result = 21 (randomly chosen)

numerator = denominator * result
```

you then ask how much is `numerator / denominator`

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
num2=rand()%9+1;
quo=rand()%10;
num = quo * num2;
printf("\n%d / %d = ",num,num2);
```

Also, you should move the `srand()` call to *before* of the loop.  Otherwise if somebody answers a question too quickly they'll get the same question again.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
float quo=(float)num/num2;
printf("%f\n", quo);
```

and print the exact result

if you want random numbers that are divideable between themselves then you want something else.

also you don't initiate `num` before `num/num2;` and you don't check if num2 is zero so you might get thrown.

finaaly you can do something like

```
num2=rand()%10;
num=rand();
while((float)num/num2 != (float)(num/num2))
    num=rand();
int quo=num/num2;
```

if absolutly can accept only divideable couples

Answer (score 0):

Test with the modulus operator:

```
int test, result;

test = 6%3;  //test == 0
if(test == 0) result = 6/3; //test passes, assignment made

test = 7%3; //test == 1
if(test == 0) result = 7/3; //test fails, assignment not made
```

This will guarantee ratios resulting in integer values .

***Also***, a random generator function may make things easier, something like this:

```
int randGenerator(int min, int max)
{
    int random, trying;

    trying = 1;         
    while(trying)
    {
        srand(clock());
        random = (rand()/32767.0)*(max+1);
        (random >= min) ? (trying = 0) : (trying = 1);
    }
    return random;
}
```

Comment: Your welcome,  You might also try to just write a simple random generator, say with max and min that will spit out integers.  I will edit my answer above with this function.

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

int x,num,num2,ans,quo,score=0;
  time_t t;

clrscr();
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

```
for(x=0;x<5;x++)
{
num2=rand()%9;

if(num2==1)
{
 srand((unsigned) time(&t));
 num=rand()%9;
}
else if(num2==2)
{
 srand((unsigned) time(&t));
 num=(rand()%9+1)*2;
}
else if(num2==3)
 {
  srand((unsigned) time(&t));
  num=(rand ()%9+1)*3;
 }
else if(num2==4)
 {
  srand((unsigned) time(&t));
  num=(rand()%9+1)*4;
 }
else if(num2==5)
 {
  srand((unsigned) time(&t));
  num=(rand()%9+1)*5;
 }
else if(num2==6)
 {
  srand((unsigned) time(&t));
  num=(rand()%9+1)*6;
 }
else if(num2==7)
 {
  srand((unsigned) time(&t));
  num=(rand()%9+1)*7;
 }
else if(num2==8)
 {
  srand((unsigned) time(&t));
  num=(rand()%9+1)*8;
 }
else if(num2==9)
 {
  srand((unsigned) time(&t));
  num=(rand()%9+1)*9;
 }
else if(num2==10)
 {
  srand((unsigned) time(&t));
  num=(rand()%9+1)*10;
 }
else
 {
  clrscr();
  printf("");
 }

quo=num/num2;
clrscr();
gotoxy(30,14);
printf("\n%d / %d = ",num,num2);
printf("\nAns: ");
scanf("%d",&ans);
```

}